# SQL Limit digits limit dash and characters to the right, but if NO dash still show the field data

Tags: sql-server, substring, iif

I'm using this in a SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio, so that if the column `dbo.Material_Trans.Lot` has a dash the dash and all the string to the right is removed.

```
SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot))
```

However, if the `dbo.Material_Trans.Lot` column does not contain a `'-'`, then it returns nothing. I would like an `IIF` statement that if the `dbo.Material_Trans.Lot` does not contain a `'-'` return the `dbo.Material_Trans.Lot` column, else do the

```
SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot))
```

Thank you!

I have tried the `IIF` and it fails within SQL as invalid statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique constraint over a generated column. For example:

```
create table t (a varchar(20));

insert into t (a) values ('Hello-World'), ('Theremin'), ('-123');

alter table t add clean_data as case when charindex('-', a) = 0 
                                then a
                                else substring(a, 0, charindex('-', a) ) 
                                end;

alter table t add constraint uq_clean_data unique (clean_data);

insert into t (a) values ('Happy'); -- Succeeds

insert into t (a) values ('Hello-Tom'); -- Fails as expected
```

Result:

```
 a            clean_data 
 ------------ ---------- 
 Hello-World  Hello      
 Theremin     Theremin   
 -123                    
 Happy        Happy
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vF56axxg).

Comment: Thanks "The Impaler". Though I have no idea how to include this Case statement with in my current  SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot)) . Which creates a unique column of data.

Comment: @RickWN Updated the answer. Now it creates a unique column with the clean data.

Comment: Please can someone provide the correct SQL Statement? Im using this as a Column in SQL Manager SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot)) . It removes the '-' dash and all  characters to the right. However, if a Lot does not have a '-' it returns null /blank.   I need to see how should the SQL code be written if LOT does not contain '-' then show Lot, else if Lot has '-' then do SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot)).  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally prefer `CASE` expressions over `IIF()` as `IIF()` is not part of the ansi standard. But `COALESCE()` + `NULLIF()` can also work here and may be more efficient:

```
SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0,    
   COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot),0),LEN(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot)) 
)
```

The `CASE` expression would look like this:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot) > 0 THEN
      SUBSTRING(dbo.Material_Trans.Lot, 0, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Material_Trans.Lot))  
    ELSE dbo.Material_Trans.Lot END
```

Comment: Joel Coehoorn.  This was perfect and thank you! You explained about IF vs CASE and how to include my prior statement within the CASE. This type of detail with explanation is exceptional!